# Just installed 14.04 LTS on new computer no ethernet

Tags: internet, ethernet

I know the ethernet controller is : Qualcomm Atheros Device e0a1 (rev 10) from lspci, and I think the problem is that I have no network interface adapter.  I have no internet access on the computer, but I can download whatever on my laptop and move it over with an usb drive.  I already added the following lines to /etc/network/interfaces:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

but don't know what else to do.